# Does anyone know about availability of Native SDK for Fly phones?

Tags: mobile, sdk

Is anyone out there aware of any native SDK to develop on [Fly phones](http://fly-phone.com/). I understand that this a non standard development platform- but we have reasons to consider this phone for a product in India.

--Kiran Kumar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fly phones are not based on one (same) platform, so if you are looking for native system support, you should first detect what phones you want to develop against.

E.g. if you choose Fly PC200, that device has Windows Mobile 6.0 operating system, so you should go and take [Windows Mobile 6 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=06111A3A-A651-4745-88EF-3D48091A390B&displaylang=en). Same applies to Fly PC100 (WM6) or Fly IQ-120 (WM5).

If you want to target a wider range of Fly phones, you will have to opt for Java ME development instead of native development.

Last, some Fly phones such as Fly SX200 do not have even support for Java, so you have to be an OEM partner to get access to particular proprietary platform source code and SDK (if any) in order to build your application.